# Is there a openFDA Data Pipeline version supported for Windows?

Tags: openfda, api

Everything in the openFDA data pipeline API seems Linux-centric, including several dependencies; dependencies require me to compile the source because packages only exist for Linux (like leveldb).

I don't want to go through all the trouble to find it still not working. So, is this supported for Windows?

Comment: to use their api you shouldn't have to install anything.....if you want to edit the code supporting the api, quick glance at github repo shows nothing i see as non-windows....that being said, i've learned the hard way to not use windows for dev, because most things are built in linux/os x and you're going to have a hard time setting it up on windows out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

We have not heard of anyone running the openFDA data pipeline on Windows. That being said, it should in theory be possible since we are using open source tools that work across platforms. If you decide to go down this path, I recommend you use Docker as it should make parts of the system much easier to support on Windows. Finally, PRs are always welcome!